# How do I bind str and text?

Tags: iphone, string, xcode, binary

- (IBAction) changeProductText:(NSString *)str;{
  lblProductTxt.text = str;
  }

I have that and i am trying to make it so that i can have the str and @"text" but i don't know how to bind them together.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean "bind them together"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your issue, but the code you posted had an extra semi-colon. You have:

```
-(IBAction)changeProductText:(NSString *)str; //Problem is here
{
    lblProductTxt.text = str;
}
```

It should be

```
-(IBAction)changeProductText:(NSString *)str
{
    lblProductTxt.text = str;
}
```

You should try using the following code in your IBAction to know if str actually has a value:

```
NSLog(@"Value of String: %@", str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to append two strings?  Use [`stringByAppendingString:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:):

```
- (IBAction) changeProductText:(NSString *)str
{
    // set label text to str followed by "text"
    lblProductTxt.text = [str stringByAppendingString:@"text"];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Please give an example.